# How to use a query to populate a table in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am not sure why this is giving me trouble; I have researched it pretty thoroughly but I have not found a good solution.

I have a table called Student that has a column called ClassDescription. I have a query that pulls the right data here:

```
SELECT Description AS ClassDescription FROM Class AS CL INNER JOIN Student ON CL.StudentId = Student.Id
```

So when I run this, I have the right results. For example, my results might be:

```
1. ClassDescription1
2. ClassDescription2
3. ClassDescription3
```

So in my Student table I would be, if I have 3 entries:

```
Student1 - ClassDescription1
Student2 - ClassDescription2
Student3 - ClassDescription3
```

I have tried using a Lookup but you can't actually make a query in the Expression Builder?

I can't seem to actually populate the ClassDescription column in the Student table. I have the correct query, but I can't link them appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
Update Student  INNER JOIN Class as CL   ON CL.StudentId = Student.Id
set ClassDescription =Description
where ClassDescription is null
```

---

**Using Data Macros - to update a record in another table.**

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but does the order of the `ON` clause have an affect?  i.e the `Student` table is on the left of the join, so should it also be on the left of the `ON` clause?

Comment: Is there a way to fire this query each time the Description column is changed in the Class table?

Comment: @Darnold14 Yes, use you can use Table After Update event.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook We want to update matching records in both tables so inner join.

Comment: @Santosh That wouldn't update records in both tables - it would only update `Student.ClassDescription` to the value in `Class.Description` based on the ID, not the other way around.  But that aside - I was asking about the ordering of the tables in the `ON` clause, not the type of join itself.  Shouldn't it be `ON Student.Id = CL.StudentId`. As I said - not sure if it matters or not.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook  `a=b` or `b=a`  I don't think it matters but not sure.

Comment: @Darnold14 Did this help?

Comment: Yes, it does. I am toying around with it and seeing if I can do this w/out a Macro but I'll up your answer since it's technically correct.

Comment: @Darnold14 Thank you!

Comment: @Santosh is there a way to call an Update when I just add values myself to the table without explicitly writing an INSERT query?

Comment: You mean when a record to Class table is added, it should be added to student table?

Comment: I guess what I am saying is the UpdateAfter isn't working when I edit in-line.

Comment: `After Update` event will work when `Description` field is updated in Class table. do you have an issue with this?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to change the value in the Student table.

Comment: @Darnold14 I have saved sample file here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xXN8yJzAANbI6SjmMzxlb7zqx2z2geA5/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

If the row exists but needs extra data, you want `update`

```
Update Student
Set Description =
(
SELECT Description 
FROM Class as CL 
where CL.StudentId = Student.Id
)
```

Comment: Is there a way to have this query fire whenever data is changed. Like if I were to change the Description column, I would want this query to re-fire.

Comment: Nope. In that case I'd just hold the data as a query in access, not updating the student table at all...

Comment: I see, but where would that be linked up?

Answer (score 0):

If your `Classes` table already links a student to a class, why do you need a `Class Description` field in your `Students` table? That's defeating the whole point of having a relational database.

Depending on what you want to do with the class description, there are far better ways to do what you want: If you want to display the student information (maybe ID and name) and class description, you can create a query that displays what you need. If you need to display it on a form, you can do that as well (e.g. using a combo box).